# WordPress Connection String

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have tasked with a job to update a wordpress site but I do not seem to be able to find the Username and password to log into the database. The wp-config.php is not there all I can see is the wp-config-sample.php I have checked to see if there are any hidden files.

Is there a particular word that I could search for to easily find the connection string in a php file? I am using search in file function in notpad++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can find in the [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php), the following strings are used to define the database connection:

> /** The name of the database for WordPress */
>
> define( 'DB_NAME', 'database_name_here' );
>
> /** MySQL database username */
>
> define( 'DB_USER', 'username_here' );
>
> /** MySQL database password */
>
> define( 'DB_PASSWORD', 'password_here' );
>
> /** MySQL hostname */
>
> define( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost' );

I hope this can help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I was at error, I was not granted permissions to see all of the files in the folder therefore I could not find what I was looking for. I will mark your answer as best thanks again :)

Comment: @Sweb If you have solved the issue please post your solution, mark this solution as answer or delete your question, it's a bit weird leave questions open when they are solved.

Comment: define('DB_HOST', 'mysql'); - where do i find the hostname?